# How to check first time social login Google and Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, google-signin

I want to call an Activity one time only when a user signups for the first time.
How can I check if the user is signing-up for the first time or not?

Have already tried this code but is not working

```
if (GoogleApiClient.isConnected(){
   Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(GoogleApiClient);
   GoogleApiClient.disconnect();
   GoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's onStart method, check if a user has already signed in to your app with Google.

// Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
// the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
updateUI(account);
```

If GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount returns a GoogleSignInAccount object (rather than null), the user has already signed in to your app with Google. Update your UI accordingly—that is, hide the sign-in button, launch your main activity, or whatever is appropriate for your app.

If GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount returns null, the user has not yet signed in to your app with Google. Update your UI to display the Google Sign-in button.
you can read this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)